# Android Game: GoogleApiClient Crash

Tags: android, api, client

i have developed a game with Java Canvas. Now i want to add leaderboards from google.
At first i have to do the login with the google account. But it crashes at start.

This is my error log(sorry for that):
[image: ErrorLog Part #1]
[image: ErrorLog Part #2]
[image: ErrorLog Part #3]
[image: ErrorLog Part #4]
[image: ErrorLog Part #5]

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.lolxdfly.mygame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" 
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4323000" />

        <meta-data 
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" 
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

The appid in StringResource: `<string name="app_id">699887223877</string>`

And at least here is my Code for loading the APICLient:

```
public static GoogleApiClient gapic;


//at onCreate:
gapic = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this).addApi(Games.API).addApi(Plus.API).addApi(AppStateManager.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).addScope(AppStateManager.SCOPE_APP_STATE).build();


    @Override 
    public void onStart()
    { 
        super.onStart();
        gapic.connect(); 
    }

    @Override public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
    { /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), connectionHint.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/}
    @Override public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause)
    { /*Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cause, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/}
    @Override public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)
    { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), connectionResult.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

---

UPDATE: It works now.. with other gapic initialisation:

```
   gapic = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(Games.API).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
```

But now i get `java.lang.IllegalStateEsception: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.` if i want to update the leaderboards!

But how could i get the not connected message with this code??

```
if(MainActivity.gapic.isConnected && !MainActivity.gapic.isConnecting)
   Games.Leaderboards.sumbitScoreImmediate(MainAcitivy.gapic, "HERE IS MY ID ENTERED", points);
```

Comment: Please post the actual stacktrace, not a picture of it.

Answer (score 0):

From your stacktrace, it can be seen that you are missing Google Play Services. You should check to see if the user has them installed. If not, you should allow user to install them.

Take a look at how they handle errors (i.e. Google Play Services not present) on the [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#HandlingFailures).

Comment: google-play-services.jar is inclueded in my libs forlder... Or do i have to install it somewhere else?

Comment: You need to make sure that Google Play Services are installed on the device.

Comment: I added the code which is mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/google/auth/api-client.html#HandlingFailures   But it didnt fixed it...same errors